# Deleted post notification masks vote count, could it be replaced?

Tags: feature-request

When a post got deleted, there is a div masking on the vote count as depicted below:

[image]

To see the last state of the vote count, I remove the overlaying div from the developer console (F12).

Could it be placed a little more to the little below?

Comment: Do @downvoters think it is a perfect place or any comment?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Please do not judge a SO fellow by duration of existance. Secondly I am against downvoting without comment especially on Meta

Comment: So no, nobody has to post any comment.

Comment: Sure it is, at least it is more "polite" and constructive. And commenting in a constructive way would add much more value to SO

Comment: Nothing constructive or destructive here. Downvote on a meta feature request (not just MSE, any meta site) means "I disagree with this feature request and don't want to see it done". No need in comments saying this over and over again.

Comment: For the billionth time, it is NOT required to comment on a downvote - it would then cause people like YOU to take "revenge" votes out on the people who "did you wrong". It will NEVER happen. That being said, I will comment - you are getting downvoted here because this would be a massive waste of development time.

Comment: @patricksweeney it is not required but commenting adds greate value to site. I don't take revenge as I never downvoted on meta instead comment

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak really? Mass unaccepting is even worse than downvoting, reputation-wise. Just for the record. No idea if you did it as revenge or just for fun, and don't really care actually.

Comment: @ShadowWizard please don't mix the things, it was a "special" issue then later I fixed, "oscillation"

Comment: I KNEW IT WAS OSCILLATION DUDE!  I also think this is a small change for a decent use case, so +1.  Also, for oscillation.

Answer (score 4):

What's the point of showing the votes count? The post is deleted.

I don't think we need such a feature. The banner is doing fine by hiding it all.

Users who can see deleted posts (the OP of a question, or users with 10k reputation) will see the score after reloading. It's one click away.

Comment: As I am mortal(<10k), I need this to see mystery

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak no you don't **need**, you **want**. There's a big difference. So you can just do what you do now, no need for SE developers to spend time on something without any real value.

Comment: Why should I miss such a valuable info such as vote count? Time to develop this is "imperceptible", just a little css, you should not blame me on this

Comment: Because the question is deleted at that point. Who cares by that point?